# How to add plaintext wordlist as a TexStudio dictionary?

Tags: texstudio, spelling

I found a [great wordlist of scientific terms for spellchecking](http://www.jpetrie.net/scientific-word-list-for-spell-checkersspelling-dictionaries/).

How can I add this to TexStudio? I have tried following the instructions on the site by renaming the `txt` file to `dic` and putting it into `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXstudio\dictionaries` - but now not only must I choose between the standard English spellchecker and the scientific one (which doesn't have common words) but selecting the scientific dictionary generates an error:

> Loading of dictionary failed: [path]
>
> Missing .aff file: [path]

How do I include this list of words in TexStudios normal en_US spellchecker?

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION03), TeXstudio uses the Hunspell dictionary format. This is rather complex because it specifies possible affixes for words. It's not straight forward to correctly insert words there.

You can specify additional words that are not spellchecked. To do so, simply place them in an additional file with extension `.ign` next to the dictionaries (e.g. en_GB.ign for the en_GB dictionary). However, this functionality is not optimized for large amounts of words any you'll probably experience significant delays if you add 600k words that way.